# Error when use JSONSerialize in flexjson

Tags: json

My program seems not working properly when i try to retrieve and serialize data from my database. I define an Object which has the following attribute:
id
title 
content
isPublic
...

Everytime I connect to my frontend webapp, it try to load notes, serialize them, and then show them on the front end.

But i got a problem when try to serialize a list of notes.
Everytime i call this function below, it just ends nowhere, and never execute right.

```
public static String manyToJSON(Iterable<Note> col) {
// if a collection is serialized do not include the content
String[] attrs = new String[]{
    "id",
    "title",
    "owner.id",
    "owner.firstName",
    "owner.lastName",
    "contacts.id",
    "contacts.firstName",
    "contacts.lastName",
    "contacts.telNr",
    "resources.id",
    "resources.name",
    "createdAt",
    "updatedAt",
    "isPublic",
    "isShared"
};
return new JSONSerializer().include(attrs).exclude("*").serialize(col);
}
```

Could it be any obvious reason? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since those attributes are apart of the Note they are being ignored since you're handing over an Iterable.  You'll want to append "values." onto each attribute so it tells Flexjson those attributes are apart of Note and not the Iterable.